# Cambiar imagen dentro de un <a> con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Quiero modificar una imagen que esta dentro de un etiqueta **a** en HTML con un document.getElementById() pero me da un error porque no lo encuentra por estar dentro del enlace. Estoy usando Angular 10.

Este es el error que obtengo en la consola cuando intento cambiar la imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo HTML:

```
<li class="nav-item" *ngIf="identity">
  <a class="nav-link" id="identity_name"><img id="image-logged"
    src="{{url + 'get-user-image/'}}{{identity.image}}"
    class="img-user"> {{identity.name}}</a>
</li>
```

Como puedo acceder a la etiqueta img para cambiar su src?

Mi codigo actual:

```
document.getElementById('image-logged').setAttribute('src', image_path);
```

Comment: El código parece estar correcto. Yo intenté correrlo en codepen y en realidad hace lo que esperas que haga. ¿No será que ese código esté utilizando algo como Angular? ¿Podrías incluir quizas el error que te está dando para poderte asistir de la mejor manera?

Comment: Una alternativa es con querySelector("#image-logged") para seleccionar el elemento, de todas formas facilita mucho las cosas si utilizas el editor de SO para hacer un pequeño ejemplo aplicable.

Comment: @ArmandoHoyos si estoy usando angular, ya edite la publicación con el error que me aparece en la consola.

Answer (score 2):

En Angular, nunca es recomendable el uso de `document.getElementById` para obtener acceso a un elemento en la plantilla del componente desde la clase del componente. Como ya mencionó hawks, puedes utilizar el decorador `@ViewChild` o también puedes manipular `identity.image` en algún punto dentro de la clase.

```js
if (condicionEspecial) {
  identity.image = image_path;
}
```

Si `identity` es un elemento dentro de un arreglo que es renderizado o si deseas reemplazar el URL completo, entonces podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```html
<li class="nav-item" *ngIf="identity">
  <a class="nav-link" id="identity_name"><img id="image-logged" src="{{ condicionEspecial ? url + 'get-user-image/' + identity.image : image_path }}" class="img-user"> {{identity.name}}</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

La renderización de la imagen es condicional en el DOM por el `*ngIf="identity"`. Si `identity` es `false` la `img` no se insertará y por lo tanto `document.getElementById('image-logged')` será `null`.

*1a solución*

```
// si identity es true se setea el atributo de la imagen sino no
if (identity) {
  document.getElementById('image-logged').setAttribute('src', image_path);
}
```

*2a solución*

```
// se comprueba que exista el elemento y luego se setea el atributo
if (document.getElementById('image-logged')) {
  document.getElementById('image-logged').setAttribute('src', image_path);
}
```

*3a solución*
Puedes mirar de usar el decorador [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description) para seleccionar elementos de la template.